# mysqli_query не передает некоторые символы

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Надо занести в БД пароль от аккаунта в зашифрованном виде. Он выглядит как-то так: òøÜâÜØÚòjl. Когда я отправляю mysqli_query с этим параметром из своего скрипта, он просто не выполняется, хотя если его отправлять из phpMyAdmin- то все работает.
Кстати, если отправлять в запросе символы типа "a, b, c..."- проблемы нет.

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `users` (`Nickname`, `Password`) VALUES ('qwerty', 'òøÜâÜØÚòjl')");
```

Comment: Какая кодировка базы?

Comment: Есть ли ошибки по выполнению  mysqli_query ?

Comment: Нет, функция просто пропускается. Т.е. весь код дальше спокойно выполняется, а функции как будто нет.

Comment: А что насчет кодировки?

Comment: У столбца стоит кодировка latin1_swedish_ci.

Comment: Сделайте запрос в таком стиле if (!mysqli_query($link, "query")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
} или воспользуйтесь ответом @Ипатьев для просмотра ошибки. Скорее всего проблема в кодировке.

Comment: @Kison это-то и смущает. При несовпадении кодировки некоторые символы просто запишутся как вопросики, но запрос все равно должен выполниться.

Comment: В base64 какой нибудь его дополнительно закодируйте и забудьте про любые проблемы с кодировками и т.п. Вообще в БД все таки луючше хранить хеш от пароля что бы его в принципе нельзя было расшифровать. При проверке пароля полученный от пользователя так же хешируете и сверяете. Ну это если вам этот пароль куда нибудь дальше, стороннему сервису передавать не надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В base64 какой нибудь его дополнительно закодируйте и забудьте про любые проблемы с кодировками и т.п.

Думаю, это мне подойдет. По крайней мере, зашифровать и расшифровать через base64_encode и base64_decode я смогу. Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Ключевое слово _дополнительно_. А то я уже видел систему где рутовые пароли от серверов лежат в БД просто в base64, без предварительного шифрования. А base64 в данных невооруженным глазом видно и ясно как расшифровывать.

Comment: А что это за $link, там?...может проблема именно в нем?

Answer (score 1):

Если mysqli_query не выполняется, значит произошла ошибка.
Если произошла ошибка, надо не гадать пальцем в небо, отчего может происходить подземный стук, а получить сообщение об ошибке, **прочитать его**, и исправить.

Для того чтобы mysqli сообщала об ошибках, перед соединением надо написать

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Вообще же, для бинарных данных следует задавать соответствующий тип поля. В данном случае вместо `varchar` следует использовать `varbinary`.

Comment: Наметился прогресс:
Errormessage: Incorrect string value: '\xF2\xF8\xDC\xE2\xDC\xD8...' for column 'Password' at row 1.

Comment: Думаю, столбец надо сделать типа varbinary

Answer (score -1):

Проверьте кодировку, пропишите ее в вашем скрипте - `mysql_set_charset('utf8');`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?